# Depthwise Conv Tensor Allocation Failure

Tags: android, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

System information

Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): yes
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Mac OS Mojave
Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device: N/A
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): binary
TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.12
Python version: 3.6.4
Bazel version (if compiling from source): N/A
GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): N/A
CUDA/cuDNN version: N/A
GPU model and memory: N/A
Describe the current behavior

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/depthwise_conv.cc:92 NumDimensions(input) != 4 (0 != 4)Node number 0 (DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D) failed to prepare.`

I construct the model with:

`interpreter = Interpreter(loadModelFile("model.tflite"), object: Interpreter.Options() {
                override fun setAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(allow: Boolean): Interpreter.Options {
                    return super.setAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(true)
                }
                override fun setUseNNAPI(useNNAPI: Boolean): Interpreter.Options {
                    return super.setUseNNAPI(true)
                }
            })`

and invoke it with:

`imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 100 * 100).apply { order(nativeOrder()) }.asFloatBuffer()
            labelProbArray = IntArray(1)
interpreter.run(imgData, labelProbArray as Any)`

Describe the expected behavior
Expected behavior is that the byte buffer would be converted to tensors of float32 under the hood as per the placeholder op.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the `ByteBuffer` handle you allocated, rather than the `asFloatBuffer()` handle that is returned. The error message is slightly misleading, the primary issue is that the API supports `ByteBuffer` types, but doesn't yet support or understand `FloatBuffer` types. The error message will be more clear in the next nightly build (see also [this fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/03d9fdf18ac40cecfb53a75d6932d8479bca6099#diff-4e94df4d2961961ba5f69bbd666e0552)), and we're working to add native FloatBuffer support.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was indeed the problem. Another problem was that I was passing in an Int array, when it needed to be an Long[][]. 

I'm a little unsure why the labels argument is so unspecific as to the type (as unspecific as it can be, I think). What led me to start using a float array to begin with was an illegal argument exception which was actually referring to the second argument. Shouldn't it more specifically ask for an array of some specific type? Or is it required to be Object. Also there's not much to understand by looking at source code in the way of comments.